# pycharm sqlalchemy Base constructor signature typing

Tags: python, pycharm, static-typing

[pycharm screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAm8g.png)

The suggestion is important on screenshot.
How does pycharm know UserMessage's constructor signature and even its argument types from defined static properties?

Can i achive the same static type checking for my classes, that work similar to Base (make constructor from class static props (types of which are also defined explicitly)) or it is pycharm compatibility with sqlalchemy?

db.base:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()
```

Comment: What is `db`? I have installed sqlalchemy, but `no module named 'db'`

Comment: `sqlalchemy` has a special support in PyCharm, for a custom class it won't work I believe, could you please provide an example? Note PyCharm supports dataclasses and `attrs` support is going to be added in 2018.2.

Comment: Pavel Karateev, ty, dataclasses is exactly what i need.